# How do I specify constructor injections when there's several classes that implements an interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I want to use dependency injection for a class that takes an interface IService in its constructor. But I have several implementations of this interface. 
Both implementations are needed by other classes as well so I cannot simply only initiate the one needed.
I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Here's an example that tries to show my classes

```cs
public interface IService { }

public class ServiceA : IService { ... }

public class ServiceB : IService { ... }

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(IService service) { }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Bar(IService service)  { }
}
```

If I did not have several implementations I'd inject it like following:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IService, ServiceA>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Foo>();
```

In the example I'd need Foo to be initialized with ServiceA and Bar to be initialized with ServiceB.

Comment: You will have to segregate your iterfaces further, so your hierachy will be as follows: `ServiceA->IServiceA->IService`.
Then when registering you'll bind your Service to IServiceA instead of IService

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (typing directly into the browser):

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ServiceA>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ServiceB>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Foo>(c =>
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Foo>(c, c.GetRequiredService<ServiceA>())); 
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Bar>(c =>
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Bar>(c, c.GetRequiredService<ServiceB>()));
```